# Подсчет суммы списка в классе

Tags: python, ооп, классы

Подскажите, как мне посчитать сумму в списке? Появляется вот такая ошибка:

> unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'Good'

```
class Good:
    cargo = []

    def __init__(self, name, weight: int, price):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.price = price
        self.cargo.append(self)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f'{self.weight}'

good1 = Good('насос', 2, 300000)
good2 = Good('трансформатор', 1, 400000)

a = Good.cargo
print(sum(a))
```

Comment: Сначала определитесь с правилами сложения. Что вы хотите на выходе получить - просто сумму всех `price` или `weight` тоже нужно учитывать?

Answer (score 2):

Вы пытаетесь складывать экземпляры `Good`, тогда следовало бы переопределить магические методы для [сложения](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__), небольшой пример (логика сложения может быть другой):

```
class Good:
    def __init__(self, price: float) -> None:
        self.price = price

    def __add__(self, other: "Price") -> "Price":
        return Good(self.price + other.price)

    def __radd__(self, other: "Price") -> "Price":
        if isinstance(other, Good):
            return Good(self.price + other.price)
        else:
            return Good(self.price + other)
```

Примеры использования:

```
>>> (Good(1) + Good(2)).price
3
>>> sum([Good(1),Good(2)]).price
3
```

Другой вариант сложения это итерироваться по объектам обращаясь к требуемому атрибуту:

```
>>> sum(g.price for g in Good.cargo)
```

Comment: не уверен, но скорее `print(sum(x.price*x.weight for x in Good.cargo))`

Comment: @splash58 По большому счёту вообще не очень понятно, как складывать насосы с трансформаторами )

Answer (score 1):

Я бы добавил метод в класс, который считает нужное:

```
class Good:
    ...
    def get_total_price():
        return sum(g.price for g in Good.cargo)

...
print(Good.get_total_price())
```